# Microsoft Outlook.com app notification

Tags: notifications, email, outlook

**Some information:**

- I have 1 gmail account for my business/work related emails only I
- have an outlook.com account for my personal emails
- I have another gmail account for non-important things *i.e. newsletters and freebie
  sites and other 'spam' type mail.*

I would like to use the gmail app on my phone for the business emails only and 
I want to use the [outlook.com](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outlook.Z7&hl=en_GB) app to take care of both personal and non-important emails.

**Steps taken so far:**

I have installed the **outlook.com app** on my **nexus 5, running the latest android**.

I have then added a secondary account to it, via the web interface on my computer. This is my second gmail account that is used for non-important things and is linked via the POP3 settings, and shows up as a separate folder next to the inbox/outbox in the outlook app.

The **app is configured to notify me by both sound and vibrations** (both options checked in the settings) - and it is configured to receive push notifications.

However, the app behaves quite strangely. For the main account (my @outlook.com address) the push notifications are pretty instant and the phone vibrates/makes a noise. **For my secondary account (gmail linked via POP3) there is no notification**, I see these updates when I open the app (it shows unread count). How can I make the phone notify me of ALL messages that appear in the outlook.com app.

Comment: Why dont you just let the gmail app notify you of your secondary emails as a push notification?

Comment: I had that setup initially (Gmail app with main account, plus secondary account), but then my work inbox gets clobbered with a few hundred non-work related emails, amazon newsletters and facebook notifications over the course of a month or so. Deleting them as they come and actioning them on the spot gets really difficult in the long run. I need to keep the accounts separate.

Comment: Also note that outlook only checks your POP3 account once every 30 minutes

Comment: I mean, have the two accounts in the gmail app. Then the inboxes are kept separate and you can easily switch between the two :)

Comment: Not true. There is an option, to set the update time to manual, 1 hour, 30 minutes, 15 minutes and push notifications. Regardless of which option I choose, the phone does not notify me of any incoming emails to my second account. I can see 3 unread emails in this folder, right now, but I had no notifications of any of them.

Comment: Ah, having 2 gmail accounts in my gmail app - good idea, the notifications would work, but then I lose the ability to manage them both from my web browser - without logging out of one and logging into another. The way I see it, I shouldnt have to find a workround, the outlook app should just notify me when there is a new email in either my outlook account or my gmail account.

Comment: The outlook app doesnt support push notifications on POP3 accounts according to the webpage i just read

Comment: You could still have the POP3 or email forwarding set up to see your emails in your outlook account on your desktop. The only problem i can see with this though is that you'll have to process all the emails twice

Comment: On gmail on your desktop you can click your profile icon in the top right corner, then click "Add Account". Then you can add your secondary account, and then to switch between the two accounts easily, just click the profile icon, and then click your other account which will be listed there

Answer (score 2):

You can't have email push notifications over POP3. It's an old protocol and simply doesn't support push. It doesn't matter what client you use or what kind of mail server.

If you can set up Outlook to access Gmail through IMAP instead of POP3, and if Outlook supports IMAP IDLE for push notifications, then you'll get push notifications. Otherwise, you might have to use a mail client that does support IMAP IDLE, such as K-9 Mail.

Comment: So, if I do not use push and do an automated sync every 15 minutes, the app should notify me of new emails to my second account? As I can't seem to even get it to do that.

Comment: Well, after a day, it is still syncing emails every 15 minutes but I do not get notified of them. Nothing in the notification bar, but when I go to the app, it shows emails in the secondary inbox. Notifications only appear for incoming emails to my outlook.com account.

Comment: @Husman I don't use Outlook, but most email clients have separate notification settings per account. Could it be you just need to turn on notifications for this account?

Comment: I have checked and double checked the settings. Having read a few threads on the internet and some of the review of the app - it appears this functionality is broken.